# Write the SQL queries to display the total amount earned by each employee's name and surname

Tags: sql

So I have two tables and i need to write the `SQL` queries to display the total amount earned by each employee. [tables in picture below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrcKu.jpg)
i tried to multiple combinations but it keeps giving me an error. could anyone please show me the way ?

here is the code i tried,

```
SELECT Employee.FirstName, Employee.LastName, Payments.Value
FROM Payments 
LEFT JOIN Employee 
ON Employee.EmployeeID = Payements.EmployeeID 
ORDER BY Employee.EmployeeID 
SELECT Sum(Value) FROM Payments Group By EmployeeID;
```

Comment: Could you share with us what you tried, and what was the result vs what you expect?

Comment: SELECT Employee.FirstName, Employee.LastName, Payments.Value
FROM Payments
LEFT JOIN Employee
ON Employee.EmployeeID = Payements.EmployeeID
ORDER BY Employee.EmployeeID;
SELECT Sum(Value) FROM Payments
Group By EmployeeID,
@Christophe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should group and sum the amounts and then than result joined by employeeId with employees to get the specific data, as name, etc.

```
SELECT
EmployeeId,
FirstName,
LastName,
sm.Total as Total,
FROM
Employees em
JOIN 
(SELECT 
EmployeeId,
SUM(Value) as Total
FROM
Payments
GROUP BY EmployeeId) sm
ON sm.EmployeeId = em.EmployeeId
```

Comment: could you please tell me what is sm and what is em  in your code ?
i am a pure beginner in SQL, so these things are still alien language to me

Comment: @MedYassine yes, sorry. No problem. "sm" is the alias for the subquery that have the group. You should use this alias as a "table name" (not real) for the specific select. "em" is the alias for "employees" tables. We use alias to improve readeability and simplify the code. Also needed for subqueries like this case

Comment: @MedYassine If you have more questions please write them here I will glad to explain it or update my answer. If it helps you, please don't forget to upvote and mark it as correct